# Книги по PDO

Tags: pdo, php, книги, mysql

Книги по PDO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Официальная документация: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)
- [Большая пачка примеров по PDO (англ.)](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)
- [Кратка инструкция на русском](http://dandreev.com/blog/php-pdo-kratkoe-rukovodstvo/)
- [Вот ещё по PDO на русском](http://php-kniga.ru/baza-dannich/244-rabota-s-pdo.html)
- [Очень подробные примеры на русском](http://seyferseed.ru/php/php-pdo-kratkoe-rukovodstvo.html)

Answer (score 0):

[про PDO и SQLite в php](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/php-pdo-sqlite3-example/)

Так же есть хорошая книга "PHP5 Профессиональное программирование Энди Гутманс, Стинг Баккен, Дерик Ретанс", но она уже достаточно старая (2006 год).