# При большом кол-ве переменных mysql не обновляет

Tags: php, mysql

Вот сам код

```
  <?php
        // Соединиться с сервером БД
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());

        // Выбрать БД
        mysql_select_db("poliklinika") or die(mysql_error());

        // Получить данные из БД, в зависимости от значения id в URL
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM  `cms_patients` WHERE  `PatientID` LIKE 1";
        $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $firstname = $row['FirstName'];
    $lastname = $row['LastName'];


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

            // Записать данные человека
            echo "<form name='forma' method='POST' action=".$_PHP_SELF.">
    <div>

        <input type='text' name='SS' maxlength='14'  placeholder='СНИЛС' value='$row[SS]'>
        <input type='text' name='CardNm' maxlength='10' placeholder='Номер ИБ' value='$row[CardNM]'>

        <input type='text' name='LastName' placeholder='Фамилия' value='$row[LastName]'>
        <input type='text' name='FirstName' placeholder='Имя' value='$row[FirstName]'>
        <input type='text' name='MidName' placeholder='Отчество' value='$row[MidName]'>
        <input type='date' name='datenew' maxlength='8' placeholder='Дата Рождения' class='datenew' value='$row[datenew]'>

        <select name='SexID' value='$row[SexID]'>
                    <option value='М'>Муж</option>
            <option value='Ж'>Жен</option>
        </select>

        <select name='NatID' value='$row[NatID]'>
            <option value='1'>Русский</option>
            <option value='2'>Эвен</option>
            <option value='3'>Эвенк</option>
            <option value='4'>Чукча</option>
            <option value='5'>Юкагир</option>
            <option value='6'>Долган</option>
            <option value='7'>Прочие</option>
        </select>

        <select name='CivID' value='$row[CivID]'>
            <option value='1'>Российская федерация</option>
            <option value='2'>Республика Беларусь</option>
            <option value='3'>Прочее</option>
        </select>

        <select name='StatusID' value='$row[StatusID]'>
            <option>Статус</option>
        </select>

        <select name='CategID' value='$row[CategID]'>
            <option>Категория</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
       <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Страна: </td>
    <td><select id='dhtmlgoodies_country' name='RegionID' onchange='getCityList(this) 'value='$row[RegionID]'>
    <option>Район (улус)</option>
    <option value='1'>Абыйский улус</option>
    <option value='2'>Алданский улус</option>
    <option value='3'>Аллаиховский улус</option>
    <option value='4'>Амгинский улус</option>
    <option value='5'>Анабарский улус</option>
    <option value='6'>Булунский улус</option>
    <option value='7'>Верхневилюйский улус</option>
    <option value='8'>Верхнеколымский улус</option>
    <option value='9'>Верхоянский улус</option>
    <option value='10'>Вилюйский улус</option>
    <option value='11'>Горный улус</option>
    <option value='12'>Жиганский улус</option>
    <option value='13'>Кобяский улус</option>
    <option value='14'>Ленский улус</option>
    <option value='15'>Мегино-кангаский улус</option>
    <option value='16'>мирнинский улус</option>
    <option value='17'>Момский улус</option>
    <option value='18'>Намский улус</option>
    <option value='19'>Нерюнгринский улус</option>
    <option value='20'>Нижнеколымский улус</option>
    <option value='21'>Нюрбинский улус</option>
    <option value='22'>Оймяконский улус</option>
    <option value='23'>Олекминский улус</option>
    <option value='24'>Оленекский улус</option>
    <option value='25'>Прочее</option>
    <option value='26'>Среднеколымский улус</option>
    <option value='27'>Сунтарский улус</option>
    <option value='28'>Таттинский улус</option>
    <option value='29'>Томпонский улус</option>
    <option value='30'>Усть-Алданский улус</option>
    <option value='31'>Усть-Майский улус</option>
    <option value='32'>Усть-Янский улус</option>
    <option value='33'>Хангалаский улус</option>
    <option value='34'>Чурапчинский улус</option>
    <option value='35'>Эвено-Бытантайский улус</option>
    <option value='36'>Якутск</option>



    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Город: </td>
    <td><select id='dhtmlgoodies_city' name='CityID' value='$row[CityID]'>

    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

        <select name='PlaceID' value='$row[PlaceID]'>
            <option selected disabled>Житель</option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' name='AreaCode' maxlength='10' placeholder='Участок №' value='$row[AreaCode]'>
        <select name='PRIKR' value='$row[PRIKR]'>
            <option>Прикреплен</option>
        </select>

        <input type='text' name='Address' placeholder='Адрес' value='$row[Address]'>
        <input type='text' name='Street' placeholder='Улица' value='$row[Street]'>
        <input type='text' name='House' placeholder='Дом' value='$row[House]' style='width: 8%;'>
        <input type='text' name='Building' placeholder='корпус' value='$row[Building]' style='width: 8%;'>
        <input type='text' name='Flat' placeholder='квартира' value='$row[Flat]' style='width: 8%;'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select name='DocTypeID' value='$row[DocTypeID]'>
            <option>Удост. Личности</option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' name='DocSr' placeholder='Серия' value='$row[DocSr]'>
        <input type='text' name='DocNm' placeholder='Номер' value='$row[DocNm]'>
        <input type='date' name='DocDate' placeholder='Дата выдачи' value='$row[DocDate]' class='DocDate'>
        <input type='text' name='DocPlace' placeholder='Место выдачи' value='$row[DocPlace]' >
    </div>
    <div>
        <select name='PolicyID' value='$row[PolicyID]'>
            <option>Полис</option>
        </select>
        <select name='InsCompID' value='$row[InsCompID]'>
            <option>Страховая компания</option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' name='PolSr' placeholder='Серия полиса' value='$row[PolSr]'>
        <input type='text' name='AgrNm' placeholder='Номер ' value='$row[AgrNm]'>
        <input type='text' name='PolNm' placeholder='Договор полиса' value='$row[PolNm]'>
        <input type='text' name='ENP' placeholder='ЕНП' value='$row[ENP]'>
        <input type='date' name='IssDate' placeholder='Дата выдачи' class='IssDate' value='$row[IssDate]'>
        <input type='date' name='ExpDate' placeholder='действ-ен до' class='ExpDate' value='$row[ExpDate]'>
    </div>  
        <div>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>
        </div>
    </form>";



        }


     ?>



    <?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$connection) {
    die('PHP Mysql database connection could not connect : ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else{ 
    $db_name = "poliklinika";
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection);

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_POST['SS']!="" && $_POST['CardNm']!="" && $_POST['LastName']!="" && $_POST['FirstName']!="" && $_POST['MidName']!="" && $_POST['datenew']!="" && $_POST['SexID']!="" && $_POST['NatID']!="" && $_POST['CivID']!="" && $_POST['StatusID']!="" && $_POST['CategID']!="" && $_POST['RegionID']!="" && $_POST['CityID']!="" && $_POST['PlaceID']!="" && $_POST['AreaCode']!="" && $_POST['PRIKR']!="" && $_POST['Address']!="" && $_POST['Street']!="" && $_POST['House']!="" && $_POST['Building']!="" && $_POST['Flat']!="" && $_POST['DocTypeID']!="" && $_POST['DocSr']!="" && $_POST['DocNm']!="" && $_POST['DocDate']!="" && $_POST['DocPlace']!="" && $_POST['PolicyID']!="" && $_POST['InsCompID']!="" && $_POST['PolSr']!="" && $_POST['AgrNm']!="" && $_POST['PolNm']!="" && $_POST['ENP']!="" && $_POST['IssDate']!="" && $_POST['ExpDate']!="")
    {
    $update_sql = "UPDATE cms_patients SET SS ='".$_POST['SS']."', CardNm ='".$_POST['CardNm']."', LastName ='".$_POST['LastName']."', FirstName ='".$_POST['FirstName']."', MidName ='".$_POST['MidName']."', datenew ='".$_POST['datenew']."', SexID ='".$_POST['SexID']."', NatID ='".$_POST['NatID']."', CivID ='".$_POST['CivID']."', StatusID ='".$_POST['StatusID']."', CategID ='".$_POST['CategID']."', RegionID ='".$_POST['RegionID']."', CityID ='".$_POST['CityID']."', PlaceID ='".$_POST['PlaceID']."', AreaCode ='".$_POST['AreaCode']."', PRIKR ='".$_POST['PRIKR']."', Address ='".$_POST['Address']."', Street ='".$_POST['Street']."', House ='".$_POST['House']."', Building ='".$_POST['Building']."', Flat ='".$_POST['Flat']."', DocTypeID ='".$_POST['DocTypeID']."', DocSr ='".$_POST['DocSr']."', DocNm ='".$_POST['DocNm']."', DocDate ='".$_POST['DocDate']."', DocPlace ='".$_POST['DocPlace']."', PolicyID ='".$_POST['PolicyID']."', InsCompID ='".$_POST['InsCompID']."', PolSr ='".$_POST['PolSr']."', AgrNm ='".$_POST['AgrNm']."', PolNm ='".$_POST['PolNm']."', ENP ='".$_POST['ENP']."', IssDate ='".$_POST['IssDate']."', ExpDate ='".$_POST['ExpDate']!="' 
     WHERE PatientID like 1;";
    mysql_query($update_sql, $connection);
    echo "Last update record has id : 1."; 
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Когда их штуки 5, то он обновляет нормально, а если вот такое количество то он при нажатии кнопки ничего не выдает и база не обновляется

Comment: Вы про sql-инъекции слышали? И вот это `, ExpDate ='".$_POST['ExpDate']!="'` что такое?

Comment: нет, только изучаю, поэтому прошу и помощи

Comment: Изучайте сразу параметризованные запросы, prepared statments иначе

Comment: @reddyk, прочитайте ответы на этот вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448720/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-extention-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81-mysql-%d0%b2-php и переходите на pdo http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/194763/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-pdo